# How can I achieve filtering with multiple values for the same parameter in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I am building a Django website that displays snowboards that will fit you based on some parameters.
One of the parameters is gender and for example if the user specifies she is a girl, then I want to display Female as well as Unisex boards - and also then filter again by all the other parameters (height, style, level, etc). Same for the boys. I want to also display Male boards as well as Unisex boards.

This is the code snippet in my TemplateView:

```
    def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        gender = request.GET.get('gender')
        skills = request.GET.get('skills')
        style = request.GET.get('style')
        rider_name = request.GET.get('rider_name').split("'")[1].split("'")[0]
        filter = process_queryset(gender, skills, style)
        queryset = Snowboard.objects.filter(
            gender=filter['gender'],
            style=filter['style'],
            level=filter['level'],
        )
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'gender': gender, 'snowboards': queryset, 'rider_name': rider_name})
```

and I have this separate function for processing the filtering:

```
def process_queryset(gender, skills, style):
    filter_dict = {'gender': 'Female' if gender == 'girl' else 'Male',
                   'level': 'Beginner' if 'rookie' in skills else 'Intermediate-Advanced'}
    if style == 'freestyle':
        filter_dict['style'] = 'Park'
    elif style == 'freeride':
        filter_dict['style'] = 'Free Ride'
    else:
        filter_dict['style'] = 'All mountain'
    return filter_dict
```

So I first tried to filter by the gender and have them both (tried both with | and with &) and then nest the QuerySet with the other filter

````
queryset = gender_filtering.filter(
            style=filter['style'],
            level=filter['level'],
        )
        queryset = Snowboard.objects.filter(
            gender=filter['gender'],
            style=filter['style'],
            level=filter['level'],
        )```

Also tried a lot of other stuff but none of it worked.
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you unite 2 querysets with and without filter you can see that filter doesn't work at all.
You want to filter snowboards where gender is user's or `unisex`. That is simple as that:

```
queryset = Snowboard.objects.filter(
               gender__in=[filter['gender'], 'unisex'], 
               ...your other filters
               )
```

I am using `in` lookup to filter all snowboards by their gender and it will return you a queryset with both male or female and unisex snowboards.
You can find more details how it works and learn more about field lookups in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups)

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was that simple. It worked :)